# Entity Framework простая одноуровневая реферальная система

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Появилась задача: написать одноуровневую реферальную систему.
Можно ли осуществить это на EF Core, используя только объект User? Чтобы связь один ко многим была с отношением к такому же объекту.

Comment: Кратко: можно. / Приведите больше информации, что именно хотите получить.

Comment: Если пользователь регистрируется по реферальной ссылке, то он попадает в список рефералов другого пользователя. Потом можно обращаться к нему через этот список.
Короче, связь один ко многим, но используется только объект User, которых хранит ссылки на подобные объекты (рефералы).